# How to automatically create timestamps for every hour of the day, once a day, in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a personal project which involves comparing forecasts to observed results. Part of this work involves, automatically, once a day, creating 24 new rows in a sheet - each timecoded to an hour of the new day, before the rest of the table is populated; e.g.

14/09/2023 17:00:00
14/09/2023 18:00:00
14/09/2023 19:00:00
14/09/2023 20:00:00
14/09/2023 21:00:00
14/09/2023 22:00:00
14/09/2023 23:00:00
15/09/2023 00:00:00
15/09/2023 01:00:00
....

So far I have found a function which can tell me what the next blank space in this column is, added 24 to that, and my plan was to find a way of autofilling from the bottom of this column up to the designated row 24 cells beyond that - however I can't seem to find a way of doing that, and I can't seem to find a way make things only run once every 24 hours.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to do this?

So far I've tried this:

=ARRAYFORMULA(ifs(not(isblank(B5:B)), IF( row() < B1, indirect("B" & row()-1) + "01:00:00"), true, 1/0))

And a few varioations thereof. B1 is a number correlating to the 24th empty row in the B column.

Comment: Would you be able to share a sample sheet with your current output and also your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
function add24() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  let o = [...new Array(24).keys()].map((_,i)=> [new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate(),i,0,0)]);
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o).setNumberFormat("mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
}
```

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 09/15/2023 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 09/15/2023 01:00:00 |
| 3 | 09/15/2023 02:00:00 |
| 4 | 09/15/2023 03:00:00 |
| 5 | 09/15/2023 04:00:00 |
| 6 | 09/15/2023 05:00:00 |
| 7 | 09/15/2023 06:00:00 |
| 8 | 09/15/2023 07:00:00 |
| 9 | 09/15/2023 08:00:00 |
| 10 | 09/15/2023 09:00:00 |
| 11 | 09/15/2023 10:00:00 |
| 12 | 09/15/2023 11:00:00 |
| 13 | 09/15/2023 12:00:00 |
| 14 | 09/15/2023 13:00:00 |
| 15 | 09/15/2023 14:00:00 |
| 16 | 09/15/2023 15:00:00 |
| 17 | 09/15/2023 16:00:00 |
| 18 | 09/15/2023 17:00:00 |
| 19 | 09/15/2023 18:00:00 |
| 20 | 09/15/2023 19:00:00 |
| 21 | 09/15/2023 20:00:00 |
| 22 | 09/15/2023 21:00:00 |
| 23 | 09/15/2023 22:00:00 |
| 24 | 09/15/2023 23:00:00 |